# Accidentally compiled with -o and no executable name

Tags: c, linux, clang

I accidentally compiled using `clang -o file1.c file2.c` instead of `clang -o executable_name file1.c file2.c` and now I have an executable with the name `file1.c`.

Is there any way to go back to what I had?

Comment: If the source file is still in the editor you can try saving it again, perhaps after a change to a comment so the editor has to save it.

Comment: Otherwise using a backup may be the only option.

Comment: This is one of the kinds of things that revision-control systems such as Git are good for.  Or more generally, backups.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C. This is no different from recovering any other file that you accidentally deleted or overwrote.

Comment: ... on that front, I don't use version control but I do copy the file extremely often, for that kind of reason, or in case i accidentally break something that was working. It takes a second to drag the file to make a copy. Make a little change, it's ok, copy that, make the next change and so on.

Comment: Avoiding such issues is a reason to use `make` or a similar tool to build even simple programs, instead of writing compilation commands by hand.  Though I usually do that more for convenience and for protection from less consequential mistakes.

Comment: Also build systems in general would work here.  Even a `build.sh` would have saved you here. Can't mess up `make` and wind up missing source code.  Typing build commands into terminal manually seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: ... back to the first comment, if there is a disaster my rule is to do *nothing* until I have some time to think about it. E.g. don't close the editor.

Comment: If you are at a workplace or school, they may also have backups running regularly that place snapshots of everything in your home directory in a `~/.snapshot` directory (the name may be something different). Search for it to see if there is something there: `find ~ -name file1.c`

Comment: I like `input files -o executable`; it seems more natural, and defaults to `a.out` if you miss specifying. (Not that it does any good in your situation.)

Comment: Ouch! Is file2.c totally independent of file1.c? Otherwise there should have been linker errors due to undefined references and no overwriting of file1.c.

Comment: This is an excessively easy mistake to make.  A command-line C compiler could really stand to check for it.

Answer (score 6):

1. If you still have the file1.c open in your editor save it.  It may prompt you to confirm that you want to overwrite the newer file.
2. Some editors will create temporary files.  Vim, for instance, create *.swp files by default and you use use the `:recover` command to restore the file from it.
3. Restore the last version from your revision control.
4. Restore the last copy you backed up.